# Vim Ruby hash indentation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, vim, indentation

I am using Vim for Ruby development and I have some annoying problem.
When I type Ruby hashes, I see the wrong indentation:

```
{
  { #Here it is.
}
}
```

How it is possible to resolve this?

I am using [akitaonrails](http://github.com/akitaonrails/vimfiles) vimfiles.

Comment: Have you tried with a hash that's actually legal ruby code? The way you type it in your example is syntactically invalid and so you don't get any indentation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try http://github.com/vim-ruby/vim-ruby

seems to be a comprehensive ruby support for vim.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I tried.
I found the solution - alternative indent/ruby.vim - http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2742